# jQuery get() function with element selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get header element from index.php through jQuery.get() function but this function allow class and Id selector. Is there any way to get element via element?

Comment: Post your current code.

Comment: Yes, simply supply the element selector instead of the class or id selector.

Comment: Why code? it just a basic function like $.get('index.php #target',function(){});

Comment: because `$.get('index.php #target'` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: Always provide a code snippet, never think you can shortcut that step if there is code involved.

Comment: Are you maybe trying to use `load` instead of `get`?

Comment: load and get are quite similar, no?

Comment: @KevinB I tried but won't work!

Comment: similar in that they both send an ajax request, yes, but the syntax is very different.

Comment: @Capripio it's not supposed to work with `$.get`, that's a syntax that only works with `$(el).load`. `$.get('index.php #target'` won't work either.

Comment: @KevinB is right.  From jQuery  The .load() method, unlike $.get(), allows us to specify a portion of the remote document to be inserted.

Comment: Oh I see... + 1 for everyone! haha

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what you're trying to do with the extracted `header` from `index.php` but it seems that [`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) is what you're looking for

```
$('#result').load('index.php header');
```

> The .load() method, unlike $.get(), allows us to specify a portion of the remote document to be inserted. This is achieved with a special syntax for the url parameter. If one or more space characters are included in the string, the portion of the string following the first space is assumed to be a jQuery selector that determines the content to be loaded.

Comment: Okey what if I want to prepend to body?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11433581/jquery-load-and-prepend

Comment: @user751564 this isn't working!

Comment: The idea that .load() will append to your selector. If you want to prepend, you'll need to recreate the load method manually with a .get().

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to parse the response body to select elements from the jQuery.get(), like so:

```
jQuery.get('index.php', function(response) {
    var gottenDiv = $('<div>').html(response).find('div');
});
```

Comment: Note, it's safer to instead do `$('<div>').html(responseHtml).find('div')` just in case the 'div' is a top level element.

Comment: Good point, amended my answer